# Giving Information with PHP,MySQL without Reloading

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to give some information from my database without creating 100 different **.php** files and redirecting users to each file according to what they want. Is there a possible way i could do that with one page?
I have a table on database named players(basketball players). I want page to be reloaded and print table players(i know how to print) without redirecting to another page which i should make. How i could do that?
For example: Player goes to my leagues.php page(webpage with information about basketball teams) then players clicks on Barcelona team and then it reload page with players of Barcelona(loaded from MySQL database). Is there any possible way? I couldn't find any similar question like that.(If there is i apologise i don't speak proper English and probably i couldn't understand it well!).

Comment: A modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) can help you organize this a lot better as they provide a consistent entry point and usually have a robust routing engine to delegate requests to the appropriate handler. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is very well documented and user friendly, and one page can be set up to receive an argument for which league to show, then filter the results accordingly. If you want the best way to avoid banging out hundreds of files, this is my advice.

Comment: You could create a RESTful interface for interacting with your database and then retrieve information through AJAX, but @tadman is right. You would be way better off using something like laravel to structure your application. Though if you're going to go the API JS route, you could also use something like lumen.

Comment: @Psyco430404 Yeah, [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com) actually looks like a great idea if this is just a JSON API, but it seems like a full application here with a front-end. Lumen would pair well with something like Ember, Angular or React if that's what's meant by "without reloading".

Comment: @tadman I kinda got the impression he was wanting to a SPA type of thing which is why i mentioned lumen.

Comment: @Psyco430404 Right on the money then.

Comment: I got it. And how i could do a php update on the same page (with reloading too) ?